# OpenScoring + PMML

Tags: machine-learning, pmml, openscoring

I'm building a new rule engine using PMML.
I have read quite a bit and would like to know if anyone can give me some pros/cons for using OpenScoring (http://openscoring.io/)? Or some performance statistics?
I have both real-time and batch processes requesting models that are going to query for scores.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The datapoint shared in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13821217 suggests that OpenScoring is reasonably scalable. To quote -

> Dataset size in the hundred millions of examples with hundreds of features. 
>   Handled thousands of requests per second, no problem.

(Somewhat tangentially to the question, but hopefully useful) - I concur with the author that PMML itself is somewhat limiting in expressive power.